# Interface VPC Endpoint Getting created without any subnet when used CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an interface endpoint using CDK(version: 1.45) with subnet selection.

```
    this.endpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, `${props.dependentServiceConfig.name}Endpoint`, {
      service: new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService(props.dependentServiceConfig.vpcEndpointServices[props.stage]),
      vpc: props.vpc,
      securityGroups: props.securityGroups,
      subnets: {
        subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE,
        availabilityZones: ['us-east-1a', 'us-east-1b']
      }
    });
```

When i create the same using console, its getting created with correct subnets and i am able to see `us-east-1a` and `us-east-1b` availability zones in aws console. But when i do the same thing using cdk code, my enpoint doesn't contain any subnets.

Documentation for the same : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#choosing-subnets-for-resources

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set `subnets` in your code?

Comment: yes, setting explicitly works but not with filter like mentioned in question

Comment: Looks like your `service` property is missing a `port` number which is required - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.IInterfaceVpcEndpointService.html. That may be the issue?

Comment: I am using constructor of InterfaceVpcEndpointService where port is optional. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService.html#initializer